# An unfair die problem. Finding the probability that $4$ of the outcomes are either one or two, $4$ are either three or four, etc.

Tags: probability

This is Exercise 6.1 from Ross' A first course in Probability.

Suppose that an unfair die lands on each of the odd numbers $1,3,5$ with probability $1/9$ and on each of the even numbers with probability $2/9$. 
Suppose now that $12$ independent tosses of the die are made. Find the probability that $4$ of the outcomes are either one or two, $4$ are either three or four, and $4$ are either five or six.

The answer states $\frac{(12)!}{(4!)^3} (1/3)^{12}$.

I can see that we should have $(1/3)^{12}$ as the probability of each instance, but I am not sure why the count of all these outcomes should be $\frac{(12)!}{(4!)}^3$. If we simply group either one or two, either three or four, and either five or six as $A,B,C$ events, then $\frac{(12)!}{(4!)}^3$ gives the total number of distinct sequences. However, each $A$ can be $1,1,1,1$ or $1,1,1,2$ and so on. So how are we able to disregard the possible combinations within each of these groups in counting the total number of outcomes?

Comment: You’ve got the exponent in the wrong place. The fraction should be ${12!\over(4!)^3}$. The number you’ve got is about $8.6\times10^{18}$.

Comment: Imagine that you’ve labeled the faces of the die with the letters $A$, $B$, $C$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left.{12!}\middle/{4!^3}\right.$ counts the arrangements of 'places' for each group of results.   We multiply this by the probability that each place has that result.

$\left. 1\middle/{3^4}\right.$ is the probability that each of the four 'places' we 'select' for `1` or `2` do each have one from those results.   We don't care which of those results we have, or what order they come among themselves, just that we have four occurances of that group.

And likewise the others, so that $\left.{12!}\middle/({4!^4}\,{3^{12}})\right.$ is the probability for obtaining some arrangement of four occurances from each three result groups.